# Why is -rf used?

Tags: linux, command-line

So I'm learning the linux command line and I come across in the book I'm reading the definition for `-rf`. 
I've always seen `-rf` used when people `rm -rf` is explained as 
"Same as above, except that if either file1 or dir1 do not exist, `rm` will continue silently."
So is all `-rf` doing is continuing on with deleting something if it doesn't exist? 
Why do people always use this then when doing commands?

Comment: Those are Linux command line options, specifically for `rm` but other commands may have them as well. I suggest reading `man rm`. In this case, for `rm`, the `r` means "recursive" (it will remove files and all subdirectories if the given item is a directory), and the `f` means "no flack" (it won't complain if it's read-only or whatever, it will just try to remove it without asking you). The `mv` command also allows `f`.

Comment: '-rf' are options specific to the 'rm' command.  The 'r' means recursive.  When you're deleting directories, you must provide the '-r' option to delete things recursively (delete all of its contents).  The 'f' option stands for 'force'.  If you run the command "rm file1 file2 file3 file4..." and file2 doesn't exist, the rm function will complain and not remove anything.  You can ignore that warning with the 'f'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while "rm" just removes a file rm -rf removes file(s) that are within a directory. So for example. if your current location is $HOME and you would like to delete everything in $HOME/robert/files you could simply do rm -rf robert/files/* if you are not a privileged user you would have to use sudo in front of your command so it would look like "sudo rm -rf robert/files/*"

Answer (score 0):

For the "rm" command anyway,

-f tells the command not to prompt at each file
-r tells the command to recurse through subdirectories

As mbratch says, the man page ("man rm") tells the whole story.